# Why does the array length change when an array that contains a pointer is a parameter of a method?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, static

I have a Node class, and when I created an array of Node pointer(Node*) and passed it through the method, I had a different length of the array as the parameter.

```
Node* hands[4];
Deal(deck,hands,4,"one-at-a-time",13);

void Deal(Node* &deck, Node* hands[], int people, std::string type, int count){
    Node*& temp = deck;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < people; ++j) {
            append(hands[j], CopyDeck(temp));
            temp = temp->after;
        }
    }
}
```

When I use Clion debugger to see the value of variables, I found that hands that I create has values of

```
hands[0] = 0x746365667265700e
hands[1] = NULL
hands[2] = NULL
hands[3] = 0x00007fc44b402430
```

And when it is passed through the method, in method the hands is

```
*hands=0x746365667265700e
hands[1]=NULL
hands[2]=NULL
hands[3]=0x00007fc44b402430
hands[4]=0x00007fc44b402570
```

What does the "*hands" stand for? And why the initial value in hands are not NULL? Actually the minimal example I can have is something like:

```
class Node{};

void test(Node* list[]){}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    Node * temp[4];
    test(temp);
}
```

But it works. And I have already written the same code in other files and works as I thought.

The deck is a simply doubly-linked list of Node. Node has an attribute "after" point to the next Node. My debugger told me before

```
Node* &temp = deck;
```

the parameter "hands" already becomes a 5 elements array.
I think I found a possible reason but I can't understand the relationship between. There are two test methods in my main function. The first one is called "SortingTest" and the second one is "DealingTest". When I comment the first test method out, my DealingTest works properly, but after I uncomment it, the DealingTest doesn't work. After SortingTest ends there is no attribute or anything left in the main method. Can anyone explain it to me? Thank you all. Or maybe my clear method is wrong so it not frees the memory correctly?

```
void DeleteAllCards(Node* root){
    Node *current, *next;
    current = root;
    while (current != nullptr){
        next = current->after;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mre].

Comment: `hands` in your program has different meaning in different context, please edit your question to contain [mcve] and clarify your questions

Comment: You're probably looking at the debug information while inside of `Deal` right? Must be some issue in how Clion interprets array sizes, but I'm having trouble finding examples of that. I don't use Clion myself. Maybe it sees that `j` does equal 4 at some point, and from that infers that `[4]` is a valid index.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The array you created is a C-Style array, which is a fixed size array with 4 elements. In your case, the element type is Node pointer.

C-Arrays do not initialize with default values, unlike many other popular languages. Therefore, the pointer values you are seeing in hands are either a pointer to a Node * or derived type or a garbage memory address with some exceptions to this rule (see below for the edge cases defined by the Standard. For the ones that do say NULL, their memory address is at ox0000...

**Update Edit** To reflect a comment made by @AlgirdasPreidZius -
For C and C++, there is a standard rule where a standard C-Array shall be populated with default values upon initialization. C++ standard section 6.8.3.2.2 ([basic.start.static]): "If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is zero-initialized."

As to why your array has those values in them from the function provided, we need more context. A reproducible example is always the best.

Your for loop, judging by the passed in parameters, is an N^2 time complexity loop with 4*4 iterations. The C-Array Node * was also passed in by reference, so when you assign Node *& to deck, the memory address marking the start of the array changes to the location of the deck array. So, it will have the values that the deck C-Array of Node *'s contains, assuming copy is a 1 : 1 copy, deep or shallow

Comment: "_C-Arrays do not initialize with default values_" Unless the array is declared with `static`, or `thread_local` storage duration. In those cases they are zero-initialized.

Comment: "which is a fixed size array with a max of 4 elements" hmm is it me or "fixed" and "max of 4" are contradicted in this sentence

Comment: @slava well, the minimum is also 4 :D

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I believe he is using C++ and that behavior differs per compiler? I might be wrong but that is what my memory is telling me.

Comment: @PaulRenton Yes, I am talking about C++, as well. C++ standard section 6.8.3.2.2 (`[basic.start.static]`): "_If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is zero-initialized._"

Comment: @Slava Thanks for putting it out. I realize it is redundant I assume this person is switching from another language. Sometimes being overly verbose can help reinforce a difference. Either way, I removed the redundancy.

Comment: @PaulRenton the problem is if that array is global as shown in OP's code it would be zero initialized. Yes that code probably is part of a function but there could be too many variants - that's why we ask for [mcve] before answering.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Good to know. The part I wasn't sure about of was local static C-variablevs a constexpr variable. If I recall, one has a memory address and the other does not. Either way, I'll update the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Slava You are likely correct that it is global because there is no Scope Resolution Operator following his Deal function. But, this function could be declared and defined in the same header, hence your opinion that we need more information.

Comment: @PaulRenton "_he part I wasn't sure about of was local static C-variable vs a constexpr variable. If I recall, one has a memory address and the other does not._" But.. Both have a memory address. There is no stipulation, anywhere, that one or the other, doesn't have a memory address. Technically, constexpr doesn't even mean that it **must** be evaluated during compilation. Only that it's **possible** to be evaluated during compilation.